# Safely adding objects to a raw list that cannot be set (Java AST)

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, eclipse-jdt, raw-types

I am working with the Java AST (JDT) and have to add `org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Type` instances to a raw list (pre-Java 5 code), which only contains elements of type `Type` (The API guarantees it). I access the list with [`TypeDeclaration.superInterfaceTypes()`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FTypeDeclaration.html) Because of how the class `TypeDeclaration` is written (there is no setter for the super interface types), I have to add the elements directly and cannot simply create a `List<Type>` instance, copy the elements, add my new element and then set the new list. Therefore I end up with a compiler warning.

This is my current code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void changeSuperInterface(TypeDeclaration declaration) {
    // some code...
    Type newInterface = ast.newSimpleType(ast.newName(name));
    declaration.superInterfaceTypes().remove(oldInterface);
    declaration.superInterfaceTypes().add(newInterface); // Type safety warning here.
}
```

Can I solve this with a solution that is more elegant than just suppressing the warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project properties or workspace preferences *Java (>) Compiler > **Errors/Warnings***, in ***Generic types*** check ***Ignore unavoidable generic type problems due to raw APIs***.

Comment: I hoped for a programmatic way to solve that problem, but it seems like this is the best solution. Thanks for the help!